# Hadoop-Vertica Connector: Can I write to Vertica in Map procedure?

Tags: hadoop, vertica, mapr

I am using Hadoop-Vertica Connector to import a large file into Vertica. I was trying to use hadoop to do that without the Reducer.  However the vertica output table seems cannot initialize during Mapping procedure, there are errors all the time.

When I check the document, it didn't say that we can write to Vertica during Mapping, so I was wondering if we can do that?

Thank you!

EDIT

This is the documentaion of the [Hadoop Vertica Connector](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/PDF/HP_Vertica_7.0.x_HadoopIntegration.pdf).

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot set record by name if names not initialized
at com.vertica.hadoop.VerticaRecord.set(VerticaRecord.java:270)
at com.vertica.hadoop.VerticaWordCount$TokenizerMapper.map(VerticaWordCount.java:92)
at com.vertica.hadoop.VerticaWordCount$TokenizerMapper.map(VerticaWordCount.java:60)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doA
```

Check the source code of VerticaWordCount.java, I found that the name list of the output table was not initialized at all.

Here is my configuration in run():

```
  Job job = new Job(conf, "vertica hadoop");
  conf = job.getConfiguration();
  conf.set("mapreduce.job.tracker", "local");

  //job.setInputFormatClass(VerticaInputFormat.class);
  //You have to set the MapOutputKeyClass and MapOutputValueClass, 
  //since by default it will be the same as the class of Reducer's
  //Output Key and Value
  job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setMapOutputValueClass(VerticaRecord.class);

  /*************Settings for Vertica output************************/
  //Set the output format of Reduce class. 
  //I will output VerticaRecords that will be stored in the database
  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(VerticaRecord.class);

  //Tell Hadoop to send its output to the Vertica
  job.setOutputFormatClass(VerticaOutputFormat.class);
  /****************************************************************/

  job.setJarByClass(VerticaWordCount.class);
  job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/tmp/input"));

  /******************************************************************/
  //Defining the output table
  //VerticaOutputFormat.setOutput(jobObject, tableName, [truncate, ["columnName1 dataType1" [,"columnNamen dataTypen" ...]] );
  VerticaOutputFormat.setOutput(job, "target", true, "a int", "b varchar", "c varchar");
```

Comment: Care to share those errors? Also, which *specific* connector are you using?